# How to build IPA for distribution with TestFlight with XCode 5?

Tags: xcode, cordova, ipa, testflight, yeoman-generator-angular

In XCode 5(.1.1) how to I get an IPA for distribution via TestFlight?

1. I set the code signing identity and provisioning profiles for the release to my distribution profile
2. I build the archive (Select iOS Device from the menu, then Product>Archive), which succeeds.
3. I select the archive in the organizer and click "Distribute..."

   1. I choose "Save for Enterprise or Ad Hoc Deployment
   2. I choose my distribution profile (same as in 1 above)
   3. I click export.
4. XCode gives an error message

> Code signing operation failed
>   Check that the identity you selected is valid.

What should I do?

Update:

1. I deleted my certificates, app ids, and provisioning profiles from the apple dev center, and from my keychain access (locally).
2. I recreated the certificates, app id, and ad hoc provisioning profile.
3. I synced my info into XCode from the dev center
4. I updated the `code signing identity` and `provisioning profile` build settings for the project and the target to use the new distribution provisioning profile.
5. I archived the project again.
6. I clicked distribute in the archive organizer
7. i chose ad hoc
8. i chose my new ad hoc distribution profile (from above)
9. I get the same error

> Code signing operation failed
>   Check that the identity you selected is valid.

(@mohacs suggestion) When I try to validate the archive, I get

> No application records were found.
>   Applications must be ready for upload on iTunes Connect before they can be validated or submitted from within Xcode.

(@threeve suggestion) When I read on [Code signing fails for Cordova app (using XCode 5.1.1 and Cordova 3.4.1-0.1.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23792406/1449799) to check the (System) Console (thanks @shedd), I am not sure where to look, but under "System Log Queries," I looked in "All Messages," and I see no messages during my attempt to "Distribute".

Comment: please let me know how to improve my question if you feel it deserves a downvote.

Comment: Have you tried Validating first and see if it is going to say "No identities are available for signing" or it will pass.

Comment: Possibly the same issues as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25212574/1375316).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @shedd and @threeve https://stackoverflow.com/a/25212574/1449799 THE ISSUES IS FIXED! Despite being unable to find any error messages in the Console, from `www`, I removed `Gruntfile.js`, `karma-e2e.conf.js`, `karma.conf.js`, and the entire `node_modules` directory.